# IPsec tunnel selection base on UDP port

Tags: linux, ipsec

I have 2 Linux hosts and each has 2 services, X and Y.
The X services communicate between them on UDP port x.
The Y services communicate between them on UDP port y.
I would like to encrypted the communication.

I know how to set-up a single UDP encapsulated IPsec tunnel between the 2 hosts with ipsec-tools (my network does not allow IPSec on IP...).

But how do I set-up 2 IPsec tunnels with different SPIs and keys - one for the X services and the other for the Y services?

Comment: Why on earth would you wish to do such a thing?

Comment: ipsec doesn't really work like that. ipsec is host-to-host, network-to-network, or host-to-network. it doesn't have a service-to-service mode.

Comment: I know what IPSec supports.
Let's say I have 2 networks: X and Y. Both have 2 sides: Xa/Xb and Ya/Yb. I have a single Gateway for each side: Ga for Xa and Ya and Gb for Xb and Yb.
How do I configure Ga and Gb to have 2 tunnels between them - one for X and the other for Y?

Comment: Rather than clarifying in the comments, you may wish to expand the question with that detail.

Comment: @cha0site This is not correct. IPsec policies can cover protocols and/or ports.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how exactly you would configure it with ipsec-tools but with [strongSwan](http://www.strongswan.org/) you may use the `left|rightprotoport` options to specify a single UDP port that is to be secured.

Example [ipsec.conf](http://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/IpsecConf) file:

```
conn base
    right=ip.of.other.host
    forceencaps=yes
    ... (other options)
    auto=start

conn serviceX
    also=base
    leftprotoport=udp/x
    rightprotoport=udp/x

conn serviceY
    also=base
    leftprotoport=udp/y
    rightprotoport=udp/y
```

Where `x` and `y` are the ports of your services. With `forceencaps` UDP encapsulation is enforced.